# why is javax.ejb.EJBException being generated when valid input is given to a page?

Tags: java, exception, persistence, javabeans

i'm currently coding webpages using jsp and i'm also using java beans. i've implemented the part where the inpuuted contents are checked against the values in the database and accept the input and store it in the database. hwoever when I input valdi data in the page, the javax.ejb.EJBException exception is thown. The following is the error page:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.ejb.EJBException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.
```

**does anyone of you know why this type of error is generated because I did not find any useful help on the net.** Could it be maybe the contents of the persistence unit are generating the exception ?

thanks for your help

Comment: "The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs." That log file contains the exception. Without the real exception, no-one can know.

Answer (score 0):

The `EJBException` is normally just a wrapper for the real exception that happend during execution of an EJB. So have a look at the nested exceptions for the real cause. It even has a method for this: `getCausedByException()` (JavaDoc says: `Obtain the exception that caused the EJBException to be thrown.`).

Comment: actually i'm not catching this exception anywhere in my code and neither the general Exception, so I don't have an idea from where its is being thrown

Comment: @ictStudent it is thrown by the EJB container (or more specifically an interceptor within that container) which catches all exceptions and wraps them with an `EJBException`, you don't do that yourself.